# How to fill ObservableCollection from two tables from DataBase?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, mvvm, observablecollection

Trying to populate an ObservableCollection from a database using the Entity Framework. Everything was fine until I started working with linked tables.

I created the DeviceCategory and DeviceComplexity model, and now in the WyeModel I try to integrate them into the DeviceCategoryViewModel. Further, in DeviceCategoryViewModel, I indicated a request for taking information from the database, but I ran into a problem. How to fill in ObservableCollection  with this information? I tried different ways, but it didn’t lead to anything, I just got more confused.

DeviceCategoriesViewModel

```
class DeviceCategoryViewModel
{
    TechDContext dc = new TechDContext();
    public int Device_category_id { get; set; }
    public string Device_category_name { get; set; }
    public int Device_complexity_id { get; set; }
    public string Device_complexity_name { get; set; }

    public static DeviceCategoryViewModel DeviceCaterogyVM(DeviceCategory deviceCategory, DeviceComplexity deviceComplexity)
    {

        return new DeviceCategoryViewModel
        {
            Device_category_id = deviceCategory.Device_category_id,
            Device_category_name = deviceCategory.Category_name,
            Device_complexity_id = deviceCategory.Device_complexity_id,
            Device_complexity_name = deviceComplexity.Device_complexity_name
        };
    }

    public void FillDeviceDategories()
    {
        var q = from cat in dc.DeviceCategories
                join com in dc.DeviceComplexities on cat.Device_complexity_id equals com.Device_complexity_id
                select new
                {
                    Device_category_id = cat.Device_category_id,
                    Category_name = cat.Category_name,
                    Device_complexity_id = com.Device_complexity_id,
                    Device_complexity_name = com.Device_complexity_name
                };
        items = q;
        deviceCategories = Convert(items);

    }
    public ObservableCollection<DeviceCategoryViewModel> 
    Convert(IEnumerable<object> original)
    {
        return new ObservableCollection<DeviceCategoryViewModel>(original.Cast<DeviceCategoryViewModel>());
    }

    private IEnumerable<object> items;
    public IEnumerable<object> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return items;
        }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<DeviceCategoryViewModel> deviceCategories;
    public ObservableCollection<DeviceCategoryViewModel> DeviceCategories
    {
        get
        {
            FillDeviceDategories();
            return deviceCategories;
        }
    }
```

DeviceCategory Model

```
[Table("device_categories")]
public class DeviceCategory
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Device_category_id { get; set; }
    public string Category_name { get; set; }
    //[ForeignKey]
    public int Device_complexity_id { get; set; }

    public DeviceCategory()
    {

    }
    public DeviceCategory(string name, int complexity_id)
    {
        Category_name = name;
        Device_complexity_id = complexity_id;
    }
}
```

DeviceCompexity Model

```
[Table("device_complexities")]
public class DeviceComplexity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Device_complexity_id { get; set; }
    public string Device_complexity_name { get; set; }

    public DeviceComplexity()
    {

    }
    public DeviceComplexity(string name)
    {
        Device_complexity_name = name;
    }
}
```

I now get an error in the conversion method

Comment: I added my answer below try it and let me know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd try to cast your LINQ query result to `ObservableCollection<DeviceCategoryViewModel>` in separate `Convert` function.

Why not to directly collect your LINQ query result to `ObservableCollection<DeviceCategoryViewModel>`

Just use like this

```
var q = from cat in dc.DeviceCategories
                    join com in dc.DeviceComplexities on cat.Device_complexity_id equals com.Device_complexity_id
                    select new DeviceCategoryViewModel    // <= Note This Line
                    {
                        Device_category_id = cat.Device_category_id,
                        Category_name = cat.Category_name,
                        Device_complexity_id = com.Device_complexity_id,
                        Device_complexity_name = com.Device_complexity_name
                    };

deviceCategories =  new ObservableCollection<DeviceCategoryViewModel>(q);
```

OR if you want to get result after list then simply use `q.ToList()`

```
deviceCategories =  new ObservableCollection<DeviceCategoryViewModel>(q.ToList());
```

Comment: not working: cannot convert from "System.Linq.IQueryable<<anonymous type: int Device_category_id, string Category_name, int Device_complexity_id, string Device_complexity_name>>" в "System.Collections.Generic.List<TechDRefresh.ViewModels.DeviceCategoryViewModel>".

Comment: Answer updated view **Edit 1** section in answer and  kindly notice this line => `select new DeviceCategoryViewModel`.